# Simple Python program with arguments not working

Tags: python

Just learning Python and spent quite some time on this. Why isn't it outputting anything when I pass arguments like this:

`python new2.py Alice`

Source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

def Hello(name):
    if name == 'Alice' or name == 'Nick':
       name = name + '!!!'
    else:
       name = name + '???'
    print 'Hello', name

def main():
    Hello(sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python doesn't implicitly call your main function.   You either call it directly:

```
def main():
    Hello(sys.argv[1])

main()
```

or you wrap it in an idiomatic clause to do a similar thing:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that was it. I was watching some older Python tutorial and guy run code without `main()` but it still worked. P.s. will accept answer soon.